# Angular - where to logout

Tags: angular

I know there are lots of similar questions, but I didn't find what I need.

In my application I need to store Users login\logout time. If user logouts manually it's fine, however he can simply close the window or browser.

I found out that there is a`window.onClose()` Function in Angular, but I don't know where I Can Use That.

Will It be in every component? Or in root component? And, what is the Most common solution for my case?

Comment: If it is a global event handler put it in the root component.

Comment: Hi Jamil, if you want to logout the user when he closes the tab/window then you can use ngOnDestroy()/window.onclose() to run the logout logic. And in your case the best option is to put it in app component (topmost component). Because it wraps the router outlet. Let me know if I didn't get your problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There's no close event in modern browser, but there's a [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload), although you can't do a lot with it, but I think it would be enough for your use

It's a javascript feature so you can put it anywhere, using root component would be better, what you do can is caching the close time in localstorage like this:

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function(){
       localstorage.setItem("closeTime", new Date().getTime())
 };
```

I'm not sure what it's limitations like if you can send an HTTP request, but that example works, you can fetch that item from localstorage when your app opens next time if you want

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `canDeactive` in route configuration.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'team/:id',
        component: TeamCmp,
        canDeactivate: ['canDeactivateTeam']
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'canDeactivateTeam',
      useValue: (component: TeamComponent, currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, currentState:
RouterStateSnapshot, nextState: RouterStateSnapshot) => true
    }
  ]
})
class AppModule {}
```

Ref: https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate